# Android Studio Recycle View Adapter Error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to get a Adapter working for RecyclerView but I can't see to get the errors to go away. Whenever I set a variable that starts with m it gives me Cannot Resolve Symbol. Here is what I have so far. I know it is not complete but this error does not come up in the tutorial I have been watching so I am trying to figure what is going wrong.

```
package jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by loser on 10/16/2017.
*/

public class CPSClist extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextViewHolder(View itemview){
            super(itemview);
            mTextView = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.lit_text)
        }

        public void bind(){

            mTextview.SetText();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: always put errors from android monitor so other can find the problem easily.

Comment: use `class CPSClist extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CPSClist.TextViewHolder>` and evene return size of array list from `getItemCount()` method and call `setText()` from `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: refer to this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) you need many changes

Answer (score 1):

**Replace this**

```
static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextViewHolder(View itemview){
        super(itemview);
        mTextView = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.lit_text)
    }

    public void bind(){

    mTextview.SetText();

    }
}
```

**with this**

```
static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView mTextView;
    public TextViewHolder(View itemview){
        super(itemview);
        mTextView = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.lit_text);
    }

    public void bind(){

    mTextview.setText();

    }

}
```

Comment: If OP tries your code Android Studio will show him an error stating "Cannot find symbol SetText() line number x". In Java method name starts with lower case letter. `setText()` not `SetText()`

Comment: actually it was written in original code by asker. i did not see it. thanks

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was missing! I also fixed the SetText() as well.

Answer (score 0):

You did not put a varible named mTextView in your ViewHolder class. I don't know which tutorial you are following but correct way of doing this is something like this:

```
    package jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.hw2;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by loser on 10/16/2017.
*/

public class CPSClist extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CPSClist.TextViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<String> strings;

CPSClist(Context context,List<String> strings){
  this.context=context;
  this.strings=strings;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_vew_single_row,parent,false);
    return new TextViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.mTextView.setText(strings.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return strings.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView mTextView;
    public TextViewHolder(View itemview){
        super(itemview);
        mTextView = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.lit_text)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @J Fletcher you could refer to this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) you need many changes